# S3 api operation failure , garbage handler

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have build on top of AWS S3 sdk an operation which uses the copy operation of the amazon sdk.
I'm using the multi part copying as my object is larger than the maximum available (5GB)
[enter link description here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjctsUsingLLJavaMPUapi.html)

My question is: what happen if all parts of the "multi part copy" are successfully done, but the last part?
Should i handle a situation of deleting the parts that have been copied?

Generally i'm expecting the copy operation to put the object in a tmp folder and only if the operation has been successful to mv it to the final name (the dest s3 bucket name). is it working like that?

Comment: I'm not fully convinced that I understand your question correctly, but have answered it, below, as I understand it.  Please feel free to clarify if I have misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

If a part doesn't transfer successfully, you can send it again.

Until the parts are all copied and the multipart upload (including those created using put-part+copy) is completed, you don't have an accessible object... but you are still being charged for storage of what you have successfully uploaded/copied, unless you clean up manually or [configure the bucket to automatically purge incomplete multipart objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html#mpu-abort-incomplete-mpu-lifecycle-config).

Best practice is to do both -- configure the bucket to discard, but also configure your code to clean up after itself.

Comment: i'll try to clarify...
have you noticed i put a sample code taken from amazon above, do you familiar with the code snippets of amazon that i have put in the origin question?
i am using the code above in order to copy obejct. 
in case of an object of size 6GB using batch copying of 1GB parts.
let's say that only in the last part of the copy the operation failed.

does it removes the entire 5GB that have already copied?
i know that an object doesn't considers as an s3 object untill it not finishes to 100% uploading and writing all metadata

Comment: The example code doesn't really do any cleanup at all.  As written, that code fails after just one exception, and when that happens, it just fails, and leaves the target multipart in whatever state it was in when the error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like AWS sdk isn't writing/closing the object as an s3 object until it won't finish copying successfully the entire obj.

i have run a simple test which verifying rather it is writing the parts during the copy part code line, and it looks it won't write the obj to s3.

so the answer is that multi part won't write the obj until all part are copied successfully to the dest bucket.

there is no need for cleanup